# Print a map in table format with header

Tags: haskell

Given a Map of Integer (Map Int Int) in Haskell I can print an output that looks like this when I use print(myMap):

```
[(1,7),(2,24),(3,7)]
```

However I need for it to display in table format with a header like this:

```
ID COUNT
1  7
2  24
3  7
```

Is there anything built-in Haskell to display a map into a table, or ways of generating table views?
Thanks,

Comment: "Into a table" is really vague; `printRow (a,b) = print $ (show a) ++ "\t" ++ (show b)` is the easiest you can get

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Sorry ... I just want it to output into something that looks table'ish like in my example :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz but what do I do about the Header?

Comment: Simply output `"ID\tCOUNT"`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I get what you are suggesting and it looks great, but I don't see how I can get my map (myMap) and pass that to your printRow(a,b) - I tried brute force (copy/paste) and I get error `Couldn't match expected type (a0, a1) with actual type Map Int Int`

Comment: `printMyMap = printHeader; map printRow`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz confused, not sure what you mean. my map is called myMap and I am printing the header by doing putStrLn "ID\tCOUNT" like you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [boxes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes) library on hackage can be used to print table views of pretty printable values.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import qualified Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes as PB

class Pretty a where
  ppr :: a -> PB.Box

instance Pretty String where
  ppr = PB.text

instance Pretty Integer where
  ppr = PB.text . show

col :: (Pretty a, Pretty t) => (t, [a]) -> PB.Box
col (a, xs) = PB.vcat PB.left $ lab ++ vals
  where
    lab = [ppr a]
    vals = fmap ppr xs

ex1 :: String
ex1 = PB.render $ PB.hsep 1 PB.left $ fmap col cols
  where
    cols :: [(String, [Integer])]
    cols = [
        ("ID"    , [1,2,3]),
        ("COUNT" , [7,24,7])
      ]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn ex1

-- ID COUNT
-- 1  7
-- 2  24
-- 3  7
```

Comment: (1) You seem not to be using the `PP` import (2) Although it works here since each row has height 1, I feel that library is missing the ability to conveniently make a tabular grid out of boxes that vary in *both* width and height.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen There's an easy solution for this as well, but the original poster didn't mention needing this behavior so no need to complicate things.